# jQuery mobile.changePage returns to first page after initial changePage

Tags: jquery-mobile

Here's a problem only with web browsers on the computer, in other words it's not a problem on smart phones as an app.

I updated my jquery mobile framework to the latest release, and i'm trying to log into my account which loads other pages, but as soon as it loads the other pages it loads back to the log in screen. My question is, are there any background functions tied to the changePage function that have changed since 1.0b2'ish release which may affect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been several changes made to the `$.mobile.changePage()` function including some deprecations that had code removed for the 1.0 release (latest at the time of this writing).

If you go here: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/, and search for "changePage", you will find some interesting information like this:

> Removed support for the alpha signature of $.mobile.changePage() in
>   preparation for  1.0. Folks now how to use the signature that requires
>   the toPage (url or element) as the first arg, and options object as
>   the 2nd. See the events API documentation and commit log for more
>   info.

You could also take a look at the documentation for `$.mobile.changePage()` and make sure the current documentation fits with how you are currently using the function: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/methods.html

Updated doc link for `1.1.0`: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: I've come to the conclusion there might be something in my code that's not interacting right with the new settings, but I found for my purpose, just breaking the code by inserting some undefined variable works. It doesn't solve the problem of making it work on web browsers, but it stops from going back and that's all i need right now.

Comment: I am having the same issue, and I don't know why is this an accepted answer. There is no information here, other than the blog links, which everyone know.

Comment: @PriyankBolia The point of my answer is to state that since `1.0b1` the `$.mobile.changePage()` function has changed so dramatically that you will have to update your code to update to `1.0` or `1.1.0`.